# Menu items disappear after loading the page

Tags: javascript, php, css

My menu items disappear after 1 second, please see page
https://stoptek.ie/
Can someone please point out where the problem is persisting in CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #menu-Mega has an z-index of -1, remove that and you will be fine

Comment: you´re welcome ;)
if it fixes your problem mark the answer as correct, so noone else needs to put effort into it